# MongooseJS markModified not working with trim

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Schema:

```
var Variation = new Schema({
  upc: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  }
},{ _id : false });

var Product = new Schema({
  variations: {
    type: [Variation]
  }
});
```

The upc field contains: ' 82943949232'

Code to update:

```
Product.findById('11212121212121212', function(err, p) {
    p.markModified('variations');
    p.save(function(e, product) {
      console.log(product);
    });
});
```

Field still has space.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `trim()` is executed when the value is set. When you mark the embedded document as modified, `set()` is not called, and because of that `trim()` is not called either.